# How to eliminate repeated values in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, arrays, json

I am getting data in 3 array with repeated IP and risk. IP may have many risk , like:

```
ip=[1.1.1.0, 1.2.2.2,1.1.1.0,1.2.2.2, 192.168.1.1,192.168.1.1]
risk=[bot, bot, conn, conn,conn,bot]
data=[0,9,2,7,8,9]
```

How to manipulate these array to get expected JSON result in Nodejs.
desired result:

```
 result=   {
 ip:[1.1.1.0, 1.2.2.2,192.168.1.1];
 dataset:[
    {risk:bot,
    data:[0,9,9]
   },
  {risk:conn,
    data:[2,7,8]
   },
 ]
```

Attempted code:

```
  letchartdata = {};
  chartdata.ip = [];
  chartdata.data = [];
  chartdata.risk = [];
  if (riskIps) {
    for (leti = 0; i < Object.entries(riskIps).length; i++) {
      letip = Object.values(riskIps[i])[0];
      for (const [key, value] ofObject.entries(riskIps[i])) {
        if (key !== 'ip' && value != 0) {
          chartdata.ip.push(ip);
          chartdata.data.push(value.toFixed(2));
          chartdata.risk.push(key);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself?  It's also not clear (to me) what your algorithm/rules are for converting from the first set of data to the second.  You need more words about how that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over your risk array and map risk with data. You can use `Set` to get unique `ip`

```js
const ip = ['1.1.1.0', '1.2.2.2','1.1.1.0','1.2.2.2', '192.168.1.1','192.168.1.1'],
      risk = ['bot', 'bot', 'conn', 'conn','conn','bot'],
      data = [0,9,2,7,8,9],
      dataset = Object.values(risk.reduce((res, r, i) => {
        res[r] = res[r] || {risk: r, data: []};
        res[r].data.push(data[i]);
        return res;
      }, {})),
      result = {ip: [...new Set(ip)], dataset}
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array.reduce to create the desired result. You can use a Set for the ip addresses to ensure no duplicates are added.

For example:

```js
const ip = ['1.1.1.0', '1.2.2.2','1.1.1.0','1.2.2.2', '192.168.1.1','192.168.1.1'];
const risk = ['bot', 'bot', 'conn', 'conn','conn','bot'];
const data = [0,9,2,7,8,9]

let result = ip.reduce((acc, ip, index) => {
    // Add the ip address to the set... 
    acc.ip.add(ip);
    let riskType = risk[index];
    let dataset = acc.dataset.find(ds => ds.risk === riskType);
    if (!dataset) {
        dataset = { risk: riskType, data: [] }
        acc.dataset.push(dataset);
    }
    dataset.data.push(data[index]);
    
    return acc;
}, { ip: new Set(), dataset: [] })
 
result.ip = [...result.ip];
console.log("Result:", result);
```